# Find the bounding box that contains all <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have *(1)* :

- a big container : `<div id="container">` which has `absolute` positionning
- inside this container, *lots* of `<div class="txt">` which have `absolute` positionning as well

[image]

I would like to find the coordinates of a **bounding box** that contains all the `<div class="txt">` elements. I have this code :

```
minX = 1000000, maxX = - 1000000;
minY = 1000000, maxY = - 1000000;
$(".txt").each(function(index) {
  minX = Math.min(minX, parseFloat($(this).css("left")));
  maxX = Math.max(maxX, parseFloat($(this).css("left")));
  minY = Math.min(minY, parseFloat($(this).css("top")));
  maxY = Math.max(maxY, parseFloat($(this).css("top")));
});
```

I don't think it's really correct because `maxX` will contain the max of each element's `left` , thus the max of the **top-left-corner** of each element. So the bouding-box **will not** contain the `<div>` which is the most on the left.
Then, in order to take this into account, I could compute

```
maxX = Math.max(maxX, parseFloat($(this).css("left")) + parseFloat($(this).css("width")))
```

but it begins to be dirty.

**Is there a more elegant way to know the bounding box of lots of elements ?**

---

*Notes : (1)* : It is for my project named [BigPicture](http://bigpicture.bi/demo), *the div name are a little different on the website*.

*(2)* : would this fit more in codereview.SE ?

Comment: By the way I like your project, good luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Comment: Something like this, But code on your

Comment: Maybe you can use [`.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect) ?

Comment: Yes .getBoundingClientRect more faster ! http://stackoverflow.com/a/22480938/622813

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

Comment: Think about if you have 1000 of elements, Try to use native JS and getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Thanks for your comments about the project @estshy @l2aelba ! If you like vegetables, don't forget to see the `recipe of moussaka` here : http://bigpicture.bi/Legumes   (look at "Aubergines") ;)

Comment: @l2aelba : Only problem with `.getBoundingClientRect()` : it gives screen coordinates (ie topleft corner is 0,0), but not coordinates in `absolute` positionning in the `container` `<div>`...

Comment: Another important thing : would you do a loop on all `txt` elemnts with jQuery `each` or something else ? (for performance)

Comment: Use , for() or ForEach()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using jQuery, with [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) it is probably easier to get the coordinates of the elements, use [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) to get the other needed values. The values are already numbers so there is no need for the parsing functions.

```
$(".txt").each(function(index) {
    var position = $(this).position();
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();

    minX = Math.min(minX, position.left));
    maxX = Math.max(maxX, position.left + width);
    minY = Math.min(minY, position.top);
    maxY = Math.max(maxY, position.top + height);
});
```

You could also consider using vanilla JavaScript, [here](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) a link that could help you port your codebase.

In case IE < 9 compatibility is not needed:

```
var textElements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt');
for(var i = 0; i < textElements.length; ++i){
    minX = Math.min(minX, textElements[i].offsetLeft);
    maxX = Math.max(maxX, textElements[i].offsetLeft + textElements[i].offsetWidth);
    minY = Math.min(minY, textElements[i].offsetTop);
    maxY = Math.max(maxY, textElements[i].offsetTop + textElements[i].offsetHeight);   
}
```